# Calculate the norm of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm working with operators and I have two questions about their norm.

1) Usually, to find a norm I apply the operator to a chosen function and I basically see what happens. Provided that the test function needs to belong to the initial space, how do I "cleverly" choose one?

2) I also found this : let $T:V\rightarrow W$ and consider the domain of the operator, which will obviously be $D_t \subset V$ $$||T||=sup_{x \in D_t, x\not=0} {||Tf||_W \over ||f||_V}$$

But how do I recognise the domain of an operator? Is it simply where it operates? i.e. (few examples):

1) $T:L^1(R)\rightarrow L^1(R)$, $Tf=\int_Re^xf(x)dx \rightarrow D_T=R$

2) $T:L^1(R)\rightarrow L^1(R)$, $Tf=\int_0^1e^xf(x)dx \rightarrow D_T=[0,1]$

3) $T:L^2(0,2)\rightarrow L^2(0,2)$, $Tf= {f(x) \over 1-x}\rightarrow D_T=(0,2)$ excluding $1$?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first two operators don't depend on $f$ though.

Comment: Anyway, the question should always specified what the domain is if they are asking about the operator norm. Otherwise, you may assume the domain is the given vector space. For example, the domain of the first operator is $L^1(R)$.

Comment: You're right about the dependancy on $f$, that was a silly oversight, fixed it. But alright, in the problems I've faced until now it's never specified, which is why usually the option 1) is what I go with. Thank you.

Comment: And your question about how one "cleverly" chooses the test function, one essentially starts with bounding $\|Tf\|_W$ in terms of $\|f\|_V$ for any $f\in D(T)$, i.e. find a constant $C>0$ such that $\|Tf\|_W\le C\|f\|_V$ for any $f\in D(T)$. You would then try to find a test function $f$ such that $\|Tf\|_W = C\|f\|_V$.

Comment: That is usually what I do, the issue is how to choose $f$. I mainly "guess" and it usually works with basic functions (like $1$), but I wouldn't know what to look for if I had more complex requirements to meet. For example, for $||Tf||_W\le \root\of\pi ||f||_V$ uses the test function $f(x)={1 \over 1+x^2}$ and I'm not sure based on what. Does it relate to the spaces? I know it has to belong to the initial one, but can I extrapolate a specific function from them rather than a generic rule? Or any will do?